# How to ensure the existence of something for every member?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In this project I am working on, there is a Course object, which has many Users and has many Assignments. Each Assignment should have a Submission for each User in the Course. Is there a preferred way to achieve this? I need it to go back and create a Submission for a User on all existing Assignments in the course if the user is added to the Course late, so I can't really just do it on Assignment creation.

Thanks!

Comment: Read about [associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) and [validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html)

Comment: I don't think validations will work how I need them to. I ended up just creating a method that will create a Submission for every User belonging to the same Course as the Assignment. I call this on an Assignment when it is created and on all existing Assignments when a User joins a Course. I don't really like that it has to iterate every user for every assignment every time a new user joins, but I don't see any better solution.

Comment: I do not understand is the submission obligatory or not ?